# Find number of paths in a graph

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I tried to get a code that can calculate the number of paths in a directed graph and i ve come to get two codes. First code using a networkx graph as a parameter and the other one with the adjacency list of the graph but both of them give me the same wrong answer so i was wondering if anyone could help me. Thank in advance

```
def caminos(G, u, v):
  H = G.copy()
  for x in H.node:
    H.node[x]['caminos'] = 0
  H.node[u]['caminos'] = 1
  abiertos = [u]
  while abiertos:
    x = abiertos.pop()
    k = H.node[x]['caminos']
    for y in H.adj[x]:
        H.node[y]['caminos'] += k
       abiertos.append(y)
       return H.node[v]['caminos']

def caminos(LA, u, v):
# LA: adjacency list
# Vertex numbered
# from 0 to len(LA) - 1.
n = len(LA)
caminos = n * [0]
caminos[u] = 1
abiertos = [u]
while abiertos:
    x = abiertos.pop()
    k = caminos[x]
    for y in LA[x]:
        caminos[y] += k
        abiertos.append(y)
return caminos[v]
```

EDIT: I did a try with both codes and the result is in the picture [Picture of results and graph used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxBr3.png)

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: From simple to complex. Please try to use only a small number of edges, that you can manually check, say 10. What is the difference between the missing edges and your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Your bug is in this line: `caminos[y] += k`, try incrementing by 1 to represent "one more path leading to `y`".

Also, consider using a different variable name.  Having a variable `caminos` and a function `caminos` is valid, but potentially confusing.  Example:

```
def caminos(LA, u, v):
    # LA: adjacency list
    # Vertex numbered
    # from 0 to len(LA) - 1.
    n = len(LA)
    pathcnt = n * [0]
    pathcnt[u] = 1
    abiertos = [u]
    while abiertos:
        x = abiertos.pop()
        k = pathcnt[x]
        for y in LA[x]:
            pathcnt[y] += 1
            abiertos.append(y)
    return pathcnt[v]
```